# Bulk Windows 7->10 upgrade

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10

I got about 70 Windows 7 machines. I want to upgrade all of them to Windows 10.

Are there any parameters than i can pass to GWX from script, or something?

Those are Win7 Professional, all OEMs.

Comment: Do you have the enteprise versions of wim7/10 (and licenses)?

Comment: Professional, OEMs

Comment: You don't need GWX installed in order to upgrade to Windows 10.  You should just push the Windows 10 update to your machines.  You are using a WSUS server right?

Comment: Nope, I'm not using WSUS.

Answer (score 1):

The best 2 options that we have used were from a command prompt and powershell.  To start the upgrade process via an elevated command prompt execute

```
wuauclt.exe /updatenow Command
```

To use powershell to start the upgrade run

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate
Get-WUInstall -KBArticle KB3012973 -AcceptAll
```

Comment: Will the first one be enough? It will download all the KBs and then what? Do I need to click "install" manually at the end?

Comment: @Matt - yes either command will work.  It will download the Win 10 update, but will not start the installer.